# dm_folder_r is not registered or you do not have access to it in documentum

Tags: documentum, documentum6.5, documentum-dfc, documentum-dql

I am a newbie to documentum and i am trying to run the following query:

```
select distinct A.*,A.i_chronicle_id,A.r_full_content_size,B.r_folder_path,B.r_object_id as folder_id 
from dm_document A, dm_folder_r B 
where any A.i_folder_id = B.r_object_id and B.r_folder_path is not null
```

for getting the folder path for the documents

I am getting the following error:

```
[DM_QUERY_E_TABLE_NO_ACCESS]error:

  "The table, gwdmpr69.dm_folder_r, is not registered or you do not have access to it."; ERRORCODE: 100; NEXT: null
```

please help me what should I do to resolve the error

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this, is to use DM_FOLDER (instead of DM_FOLDER_R) and the ENABLE (ROW_BASED) hint.
I just modified and run your query successfully :

```
select distinct A.*,A.i_chronicle_id,A.r_full_content_size,
       B.r_folder_path,B.r_object_id as folder_id 
  from dm_document A, dm_folder B 
 where any A.i_folder_id = B.r_object_id 
       and B.r_folder_path is not null
ENABLE (ROW_BASED)
```

Please note that you are querying all the dm_documents in your Documentum system, which may result in a very large result set. Consider reducing your result set by adding more conditions to your where clause.

Comment: Good point Rob. Actually dm_folder_r is a table in database under repository paired with dm_folder_s and actually holds the information presented in repository under dm_folder types. However mostly it isn't wise to use it especially if you're newbie

Answer (score 0):

Try to use either `dm_dbo.dm_folder_r` or just `dm_folder` and `ANY B.r_folder_path IS NOT NULL`

Comment: I tried two cases which you have told
for first case:dm_dbo.dm_folder_r
error is
    [DM_QUERY_E_TABLE_NO_ACCESS]error:  "The table, 
    docbase.dm_folder_r, is not registered or you do not have access 
    to it.
second case is:
    [DM_QUERY2_E_REPEAT_TYPE_JOIN]error:  "Your query is selecting repeating attributes and joining types."; ERRORCODE: 100; NEXT: null

can you suggest me what should i do to resolve the error??